# Creating a Test-Template

Tags: calculations

after hours of searching and trying i want to ask my special question. I'am a teacher and want to create a template for my test-document. Therefore i need to add points in every task. To control the maximum of points i have to manual create a sum of that but i think latex is able to do this for me. So, i want to save a pointnumber into storage and at the end the sum of all points needs to be post at the beginning of the document. Can anyone help?

Here is a Example:

Points:       / 10

Task 1 (5 Points): Find a way to you're home!

Task 2 (3 Points): Another question

Task 3 (2 Points): Here we go!

THX a lot!

Comment: Package or class `exam` or `exsheets` for example?

Comment: https://www.ctan.org/pkg/exercises: Typeset exercises and solutions with automatic addition of points

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) On this site, a question should typically revolve around an abstract issue (e.g. "How do I get a double horizontal line in a table?") rather than a concrete application (e.g. "How do I make this table?"). Questions that look like "Please do this complicated thing for me" tend to get closed because they are either "off topic", "too broad", or "unclear". Please try to make your question clear and simple by giving a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228): you'll stand a greater chance of getting help.

Answer (score 3):

I strongly recommend to use one of the existing classes, mentioned in the above comments. Personally I have had really good results with the `exam` class. Here's a example (in German).

```
\documentclass[addpoints,a4paper,ngerman,12pt,answers]{exam}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=2.5cm,bottom=3cm,left=2.5cm,right=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{paralist}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage[math]{iwona}

\pointpoints{Punkt}{Punkte}
\bonuspointpoints{Bonuspunkt}{Bonuspunkte}
\renewcommand{\solutiontitle}{\noindent\textbf{Lösung:}\enspace}

\chqword{Frage}   
\chpgword{Seite} 
\chpword{Punkte}   
\chbpword{Bonus Punkte} 
\chsword{Erreicht}   
\chtword{Gesamt}

\checkboxchar{\Square}
\checkedchar{\CheckedBox}

\pagestyle{headandfoot}
\runningheadrule
\firstpageheader{Links oben}{Mitte oben}{\today}
\runningheader{Links oben}{Mitte oben}{\today}
\firstpagefooter{Links unten}{Mitte unten}{\thepage\,/\,\numpages}
\runningfooter{Links unten}{Mitte unten}{\thepage\,/\,\numpages}

\begin{document}
\vspace*{3em}

\makebox[\textwidth]{Name:\enspace\hrulefill}

\vspace*{2em}

\makebox[\textwidth]{Matrikelnummer:\enspace\hrulefill} 

\vspace*{3em}

\begin{questions}
\question[4] Warum gibt es Luft?

\begin{solution}
Damit wir atmen können.
\end{solution}

\bonusquestion[2] Wieviel Luft gibt es?

\begin{solution}
Ziemlich viel.
\end{solution}

\question[5] Warum gibt es Sauerstoff?

\clearpage

\question Was wäre, wenn es keine Luft gäbe?
\begin{parts} 
\part[5] Was würde mit Luftballons geschehen? 
\bonuspart[6] Wie könnten Fluggesellschaften damit umgehen?
\end{parts}

\question [100] Wird es morgen schneien?
\begin{checkboxes}
\CorrectChoice Ja
\choice Nein
\choice Vielleicht
\end{checkboxes}

\question Ein Name der folgenden Reihe passt nicht zu den anderen. Welcher?
\begin{oneparchoices}
\choice Donald
\choice Dagobert
\choice Daisy
\choice Micky
\CorrectChoice Balu
\end{oneparchoices}

\end{questions}

\begin{center}
\combinedgradetable[h][questions]
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: THX for so fast and so good help - i will give it a try :)

Comment: Ok it worked but when i call at the beginning "totalpoints" i only get a ?? at this part...can find a good answer in the documentation...

Comment: Here we go . numpoints :)